# Audio player html5 play button can't working fine…?

Tags: html

here is my code for my player on www.bmixup.com, is playing for stream from icecast, i don't understand, after i push on play, stream play but after some times he's stop all time on my browser, and if i re-push on, no reaction, i am must to reload all my page....

```
<audio id="player" preload>
           <source src="http://bmixup.com:8000/BmixupStream" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
           Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag.
   </audio>
   <div style="background-color: #808080;text->align:center;padding:20px;margin-right:0em;">
       <div class="buttonplayer" style="text-align: left;">
          <button id="play" type="button" >onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"  class="btn btn-default btn->circle btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
          <button id="Pause" type="button" >onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()" class="btn btn-default btn->"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></button>
          <button id="Voldown" type="button" >onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1" class="btn btn->default btn-circle btn-lg" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-down">>>>></span></button>            
            <button id="Volup" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></button>
            <span>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/titre.js"></script>
                <span id="track-title" style="font-family: exoregular;margin-left: 1em;color: #ffffff;"></span>
                <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="200" style="font-family: exoregular; margin-top: 0.7em;color: #ffffff;">Vous écouter actuellement Bmixup.com, The mix web radio et il y a actuellement : <span id="listeners" style="color: #ffffff;">00</span>  auditeurs à l'écoute...Bonne écoute...</marquee>
            </span>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's is wrong, why stream stop after play, and don't no be constant, to, i stop, and why if re-push on play, that's not re-begging...?

Can you help me ?..

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 audio tag is pretty stable, but the stream may interrupt because of network problems (packet loss, connection problems, etc.).
The best solution is to use HTML5 audio player framework like `jPlayer` or `SoundManager2`, catch stream errors and force the player to re-connect with timeout.